# grails 2 different dependencies with same package names

Tags: java, maven, gradle, grails, dependency-management

Some dependencies from various libraries have same package name `javax.mail`. And all the classes inside them are equal with different versions.

I want to be able to choose which class to load at runtime. To be more specific, I have `MimeMessage` class for email and right now the program is choosing the old version rather than the newer version so this field `protected InternetHeaders headers;` is not correctly filled and the charset for email and subject is not added so I am unable to send mail with html body.
jar file names :

```
javax.mail-1.6.2.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar
javax.mail-1.5.1.jar
javax.mail-api-1.5.1.jar
```

all of them have `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna try to

- Exclude the conflicting dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.example:conflict-library:1.0') {
        excludes 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec'
    }
}
```

- Use dependency management

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.example:bom:1.0'
    }
    dependencies {
        dependency 'javax.mail:mail:1.6.2'
    }
}
```

forcing all dependencies on javax.mail:mail to use version 1.6.2

PS: remember to clean and rebuild your project after modifying

Comment: Thanks for your answer. my problem is solved now. but is there any syntax to tell the class loader which class to load in this situation ?

Comment: Glad it helped! There's no built-in way to specify which class to load when multiple classes share the same fully qualified name in Java tho, the classpath scanning process uses the first one found. Maybe it's technically possible to use separate class loaders to isolate classes, it's generally simpler and safer to manage dependencies to avoid such conflicts via maven/gradle anyway